# plus sign '+' appearing after links in AMP Pages

Tags: amp-html

i am trying to convert my site to amp,
i noticed that whenever i use `<UL>` and `<Li>` tags all links present within the `<Ul>` and `<li>` tags have a + sign appearing in the browser after them

so if the link says click here, it displays click here+ in the browser

the actual link works but i find the appearance of the + thing very strange
the problem gets resolved as soon as i remove the `<li>` tags,

why is that happening?

Comment: I'm not sure if you specified the correct tag for your question. This tag refers to RPC protocol for sending multiple asynchronous requests.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, give us an example maybe

Comment: <ul> and <li> tags are supoorted by AMP page..

Answer (score 0):

The `+` signs you are seeing has nothing to do with AMP errors or anything. It is a standard part of [URL Percent-encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) where instead of spaces, the URL make use of `+` sign instead.

According to this [amp-sidebar guide](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-sidebar), `li` and `ul` are supported. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I try to figure out your problem.
Is it about your dropdown menu using pure CSS?
If it is yes, the problem comes from the property and value of your own custom CSS, as in:

```
`content=:'+';`
```

or,

```
content:'&#43;
```

As far as I can see that I found no AMP-documentation related to sign +

Comment: You are very right, it looks like a CSS problem, i will try to fix it now